# Shift operator in C

Tags: c

I have an binary array of length 64. I want to find corresponding integer in C. I have 
written the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
 {

      int A[64]={1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1},i;


       long long  int B=0;

      for(i=0;i<64;i++)
             B=B+A[i]*pow(2,63-i);

      printf("B=%llu\n",B);

  }
```

Result is ok. But instead of pow function I want shift operator (<<) for efficiency. 
How can I do this?

Comment: declaration of `i` is well hidden after `A`'s; would better be a separate declaration.

Comment: You really couldn't initialize `A` better?

Comment: hint: `pow(2,x)` is like `1<<x` (if no overflow). Not only more efficient, also more accurate.

Comment: `printf("B=%llu\n",B)` has undefined behavior because `llu` specifies `unsigned long long`, but `B` is different, `long long int`. Additionally, adding the high bit (2**63) and storing the result into `B` overflows on implementations in which `long long int` is 64 bits.

Comment: Thank you, all of you, very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int A[64] = {
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    };

    uint64_t B = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        B |= (uint64_t) A[i] << 63-i;

    printf("B = %" PRIu64 ".\n", B);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The type of `B` was changed to unsigned, notably `uint64_t`, to avoid overflow.
- `uint64_t` was used rather than `unsigned long long` for clarity and precision of meaning.
- The format specifier in the `printf` was matched to the type of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
B=B+A[i]*pow(2,63-i);
```

to

```
B=(long long)(B+A[i]*(1ULL<<(63-i)));
```

Comment: This reverses the bits of the array from the order used by the original code. Also, there is an overflow problem, since the high bit may exceed the ranges of `unsigned long long` and `int` (but that exists in the original code as well). And there is no need for multiplication; `A[i]` can be shifted directly, after conversion to a suitably wide type.

Comment: `no need for multiplication` I believe the contents of the array will change.

Comment: Shifting a value does not change it any more than multiplying it would.

Comment: @interjay `I have an binary array of length 64` bit 1 or 0.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say with that comment. The multiplication is unnecessary as Eric Postpischil said.

Comment: @interjay I believe the contents of the array A is for all 1 as mere sample.

Comment: I know that it can be 0 or 1. The point is that `x * (1ull << y)` is the same as `((unsigned long long)x) << y`.

Comment: My previous comment should have said that there can be overflow with the `long long int` type (the type of `B`), rather than the `unsigned long long` type (which is okay up to the point at which it must be converted to `long long int` for storage into `B`).

Comment: @interjay i see, i can understand that being the case. but i think this way to make it better is to match the original.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i had been to that I also had to worry about. to predict it would be converted as probably no problem.

Comment: I think I ought to be answered on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has a good answer already, but here's another version.  I personally use this a part of a vertical counter implemented in c. By setting A[radix] as a bool first, it ensures that any non-zero value will be interpreted as a single bit.  Just for reference on vertical counters if anyone's interested...  http://www.steike.com/code/bits/vertical-counter/

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int A[64] = {
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    };

    uint64_t B = 0;

    for (int radix = 63; radix >= 0; radix--)
        B |= ((uint64_t)(A[radix]))<<radix;

    printf("B = %llu\n", B);
    return 0;
}
```